# Filtering repeated phone numbers in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The output has repeated results/rows - something is wrong with the filtering.

While cycling to read the SQL results the output has to meet these conditions:

**Condition 1:** The message contains no emails: `/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i`

**Condition 2:** The message *must* contain a Portuguese mobile number, 9 digits,
starting with 91, 92, 93 or 96, and it can have space between each group of 3 numbers: `/(9[1236][0-9]) ?([0-9]{3}) ?([0-9]{3})/`

910 000 000 and 920123123 are valid matches.

**Condition 3:** The `preg_match` result (phone number) must not repeat, my intention is that if someone has 2 or 3 posts with same phone number, just output the first one only.

If the 9 digit phone number already exits this cycle, output the first, skip the rest, go back to while cycle.

```
$array = array();

while ($result = $query->fetch_array()) {
    $temp = array();
    if (preg_match('/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i', $result['message']) == false) {
        if (preg_match('/(9[1236][0-9]) ?([0-9]{3}) ?([0-9]{3})/', $result['message'], $temp)) {
            preg_replace(" ", "", $temp);
            foreach($temp as $value) {
                if ((array_search($value, $array) == false) && (strlen($value) == 9)) {
                    array_push($array, $value);
                    /*HTML OUTPUTS HERE*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array();
while ($result = $query->fetch_array()) {
    $temp = array();
    if (preg_match('/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i', $result['message']) == false) {
        if (preg_match('/(9[1236][0-9]) ?([0-9]{3}) ?([0-9]{3})/', $result['message'], $temp)) {
            $phone = str_replace(' ', '', $temp[0]);

            if (array_search($phone, $array) === false) {
                $array[] = $phone;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes:

- `str_replace` is faster than `preg_replace` for simple, non-regular expression replacements.
- `array_search` can return `0` when the value is in the first element of the array, so you need to use [the `===` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).
- Lastly, there's no need for the last `foreach` loop as the full phone number is the first element in `$temp`.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, I think it's best to indicate **DISTINCT** for removal of repeated results.

e.g:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM table_name WHERE 1;
```

Comment: ty for reply, i've tried DISTINCT which didnt work, its a forum, they are creating repeated topics mixed with text and numbers, some users abuse it by changing the topic title and text writing in the topic 1st post/message but with same phone number, basically flooding but keeping the same phone number, which i need filter out, and outout only 1 topic